Can't use "ShareThis" functionality from modal
I use "ShareThis" inside a vue app initialized by the following code:
const handleExternalShare = function(id) {

    const st = window.__sharethis__
    if (!st) {
      const script = document.createElement('script')
      script.src = `https://platform-api.sharethis.com/js/sharethis.js#property=${id}&product=sop`
      document.body.appendChild(script)
    } else if (typeof st.initialize === 'function') {
      st.href = window.location.href;
      st.initialize()
    }
}

The share button is inside a modal, but it doesn't work and I don't have any errors in console. It should open another modal with all share buttons provided by ShareThis. Any ideas why this is happening?

Please, provide https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve . It's unclear what happens. You call handleExternalShare  the first time and don't call initialize(), is this intentional?

In that specific component where I need share tools I call handleExternalShare on mounted()

If you call handleExternalShare only once then "else if " is the problem. Wait for the script to be loaded and then initialize it
